# C++/QT Sharing string value with another shared library

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries

I need to read rfid value and convert it from QByteArray to QString and it works. Then I have another function which returns the data to any place I need to use it. I can use the value in executable but I have a problem with sharing the value with another Shared Library.

```
void RFID::readData()
{
//Here's just code about getting data to QByteArray variable and converting it to QString
qDebug() << rfid; //this works
}
```

Below you can see the function to return the value we created above:

```
QString RFID::returnData()
{
return rfid;
}
```

This next code is in Shared Library called Database which should get data from the first shared library. I want the next function to save the value into a variable but I'm not able to print the value at all.

```
void Database::search()
{
qDebug() << objectRFID->returnData();
}
```

I have included the path to this library in .pro just like I did with the main application. I also included rfid.h in database.h. In mainwindow.cpp I can print the value by using the same object method as seen above but somehow it works only in the executable. Search function only prints "". Tell me if you need more code or any explanations but I tried to explain everything very simple and clear.

Comment: Have you tried printing the data with std::cout << objectRFID->returnData().toStdString() or assigning the value to a variable to check its value? qDebug() can be sometimes a bit uncooperative

Comment: I tried to write the value to a variable and print after that but it didn't work any better.

Comment: did you call `readData()` on the same `RDIF` object that `objectRFID` points to?
E.g. if you output `(void*)this` in `readData()` is it the same value as when you do it in `returnData()`?